# Kahn Pseudo Normal distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable, approximation

I read about a so-called "Kahn Pseudo Normal" distribution in a [forum post](http://www.hpmuseum.org/forum/thread-7440-post-65971.html).

It says when $U$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$, then $\log(1/U-1)$ is approximately normal distributed, that is

> Averages of the ... distribution converge to a normal distribution
>   (central limit theorem).

I searched for "Kahn Normal distribution" over the web, but found nothing relevant.

Can someone give me some more explanation or background of this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is merely the standard [logistic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution).

We can derive this in a few lines. Let $U\sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$

Let $X = 1/U - 1$.

$F_X(x)=P(X\leq x) = P(1/U-1 \leq x) = P(U\geq 1/(x+1)) = 1-1/(x+1)\,,x>0$

Hence $f_X(x) = 1/(x+1)^2\,,\:  x>0\,.$  (This is a *shifted* Pareto(1))

Now let $Y=\log(X)$. Then

$P(Y\leq y) = P(\log(X)\leq y) = P(X \leq \exp(y)) = 1-\frac{1}{1+\exp(y)} = \frac{\exp(y)}{1+\exp(y)}$

which is the cdf of a standard logistic distribution.

(Such a method of generating values from the logistic distribution corresponds to the [inverse-cdf method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).)

It is symmetric but has exponential tails. It is fairly similar to a normal in the between the quartiles - or perhaps out a bit further, say the middle 75% or so - but not at all close to the normal distribution in the tails:

[image: quantile plot of logistic vs normal]

(the line has slope 1.6, approximately the ratio of the interquartile ranges)

The statement that averages converge* to a normal is hardly news; you don't need to be at all close to a normal to have that; the CLT applies quite widely.

* however the statement as given is strictly incorrect. Standardized averages converge to a standard normal by the CLT. Raw averages actually converge to a spike at 0.

Comment: In some sources I see $\log(x/(1-x))$ as the inverse CDF of the logistic distribution. This differs from $\log(1/x-1)=-\log(x/(1-x))$ in a sign. Which is the correct one?

Comment: I nowhere say that $\log(1/x-1)$ *is* the inverse cdf (it isn't), However, I do say the method corresponds to the inverse cdf method. Note that $\log(1/v-1) = \log((1-v)/v)= -\log(v/(1-v))$, Keep in mind that the standard logistic is symmetric about $0$. Alternatively (but equivalently), note that if $u=1-v$ $\log(1/v-1)=\log(u/(1-u))$, and if $V$ is uniform on $(0,1)$ then so is $U=1-V$.